# Point IIS8 virtual directory to a different server IP Address?

Tags: linux, magento, iis-8

Here is my issue (keep in mind I am used to linux not windows servers):  I have a website domain.com (.asp site) that is hosted on an IIS8 server and then a folder domain.com/folder that needs to point to a different servers IP address that holds a different site (linux server running Magento).

I know personally that a subdomain should have been created and DNS pointed to it correctly like folder.domain.com but I have inherited this issue and am trying to see if a solution is even possible.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You can try ARR to set up reverse proxy rules.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have previlage to comment in your question.! So I commenting here.!

Have you ever crossed symlinks? I hope you need the following link. The question is not clear though.

check this out. 
[Symlink created with mklink not working with IIS7.5 -- Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829909/symlink-created-with-mklink-not-working-with-iis7-5-windows-7)

Answer (score -1):

Responding as another team member on this project--

1. A 301 redirect is not a viable option by nature of Magento's URL request mechanism (if the request didn't originate from the URI set in the config, then redirect to it). We either end up with infinite loops, or IIS rewriting headers to trick Magento in to thinking the request URI is correct and performing a 301 redirect on every resource on the page (and the page itself, of course). This breaks miserably on POST requests.
2. We must be serving fully-qualified URLs from domain.com/folder/foo-bar.baz.
3. Switching to Linux is not possible. Please don't suggest what we already want.

Thanks, SO.

Comment: You should merge this information into the question, this is not an answer.