# UI-Router nested route breaking on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to be able to refresh the page on my Angular app when I load a tab, to load the tab I implemented the following:

```
  .state('MyTemplate.Tabs.Tab',
        {
            url: '/tab',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Tabs.html'
                },
                'tabs-views@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/tab.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

This works great when I click on my tab link and it loads the view with it's controls, however when I refresh the page, it reloads, it tries to load the root of the site and blows up.

I tried tricking it with no success:

```
  .state('MyTemplate.Tabs.Tab2',
        {
            url: 'tabs/tab',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Tabs.html'
                },
                'tabs-views@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/tab.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Updating with states:

```
.state('MyTemplate',
{
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'App/SharedViews/header.html'
        },
        'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'App/SharedViews/footer.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('MyTemplate.Tabs',
        {
            url: '/tabs',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Tabs.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you please provide `MyTemplate.Tabs` and `MyTemplate` states

Comment: Sure, updated the answer.

Comment: Hm, do you use default `#/` or `html5mode` in URLs?

Comment: I'm using html5mode > $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: So, it absolutely changing context, problem with `HTML5 History API` and `server-side` configuration. Can you please update your question with information about how server manages angular application.

Comment: Ah I remember the #! now, I turned on html5mode to get rid of it, turning off html5mode adds it back in, but... fixes my route.  I'd like to keep running with html5mode on, but not if it becomes a timesink.  Not sure what you mean by server managing angular application, I'm not using angular.js-server or anything, just Angular 1.6 with UI-Router for the routes.

Comment: I mean, do you use a server e.g. Apache, Nginx, Express?

Comment: Ah, of course, I'm testing it locally using IIS 10.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you could try to configure IIS 10 with something like this:

```
<rewrite>  
  <rules>  
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">  
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />  
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />  
    </rule>  
  </rules>  
</rewrite>
```

In your web.config (inside configuration/system.webServer...etc):

Also look here [Symlink created with mklink not working with IIS7.5 -- Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829909/symlink-created-with-mklink-not-working-with-iis7-5-windows-7)

Rewrite rules for HTML5 history (apache example)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(js|css|img|svc)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot soon, I've already got a rewrite rule in there for the refreshes (which wasn't working with the nested tabs), but was working with anchors.